# how to make a design in css like below screenshots

Tags: css

[i want to make responsive grides like the 6 grids in right site(image 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUYC7.png)

[it turns like this image(image 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwaLT.png)

Help me to make responsive div grid like the 6 grids at the right side of image one, and when that site opens in mobile/small devices the it become like image 2, please tell me procedure.
i have tried to make three row and 2 column in each row but when it is shown in mobile devices that 6 grid become stacked one upon one ,plz help me to figure out what i am missing.
i am new here, sorry for my bad english .help needed .

Comment: Are you working with plain CSS ? Because it looks like you are trying to make it work in bootstrap ? Clarify please

Comment: Kindly post your code that you have write.

Comment: Hey, StackOverflow is not a site to ask us to code your website/project for you. It is for asking questions, and getting help with errors that you do not understand.